# Add logo to ternary operators inside Angular Expressions

Tags: angular, ternary-operator

I want to add two different logos to my HTML depending if the status is active or not.

Right now I have this, which works:

```
<td>{{customer.activeStatus?"yes":"no"}}</td>
```

But I would like to have something along the lines of this:

```
<td>{{customer.activeStatus? "<i class='fas fa-lightbul'></i>":"no"}}</td>
```

If it is true, I would like to have this logo from FontAwesome and if false then "no".

Comment: is `customer.activeStatus` of boolean type?

Comment: yes it is! returns a simple true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `*ngIf and else`

```
<td>
  <i *ngIf="customer.activeStatus;else elsePart" class='fas fa-lightbul'></i>
  <ng-template #elsePart>No</ng-template>
</td>
```

for more details check this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: This technically works, but oddly enough the logo from Font Awesome won't load tho(event though it shows up in the browsers html source)!

Comment: Sorry no it works! Your solution works! It I had copied your code and there was a 'b' missing, now it works! Thanks!